# Google Apps Script - if else statement inside for loop not working

Tags: for-loop, if-statement, google-apps-script

I have an if else statement inside of a for loop. My goal is to have it look through existing work order numbers. If it finds a match to the one currently selected, it updates the other values for that work order. If it doesn't find a match, it adds a new row under the last entry.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const rdSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Renderings");
  const wipSheet = ss.getSheetByName("WIP");

  var cell = e.range;
  var row = cell.getRow();
  var col = cell.getColumn();


  //if status is changed in Rendering sheet
  if (activeSheet.getSheetName() == 'Renderings' && col == 12) {

    //Rendering sheet variables - active sheet
    var rdWOValue = rdSheet.getRange("A" + row).getValue();
    var rdCustomerValue = rdSheet.getRange("B" + row).getValue();
    var rdQTYValue = rdSheet.getRange("C" + row).getValue();
    var rdJobNotesValue = rdSheet.getRange("D" + row).getValue();


    //WIP sheet variables - inactive sheet
    var wipWO = wipSheet.getRange("A:A");
    var wipWOValues = wipWO.getValues();

    var wipCustomer = wipSheet.getRange("B:B");
    var wipCustomerValues = wipCustomer.getValues();

    var wipQTY = wipSheet.getRange("C:C");
    var wipQTYValues = wipQTY.getValues();

    var wipJobNotes = wipSheet.getRange("D:D");
    var wipJobNotesValues = wipJobNotes.getValues();


    //looking for existing match in WIP sheet
    for (var w = 0; w < wipWOValues.length; w++) {
      //pastes values from Rendering sheet to WIP sheet if match is found
      if (wipWOValues[w][0] === rdWOValue && wipCustomerValues[w][0] === rdCustomerValue && wipJobNotesValues[w][0] === rdJobNotesValue) {

        wipQTYValues[w][0] = rdQTYValue;
        wipQTY.setValues(wipQTYValues);

        break;
      }
      //adds new row if match is not found and pastes values from Rendering sheet to WIP sheet
      else {
        var wipLastRow = wipSheet.getLastRow();

        wipSheet.getRange(wipLastRow + 1, 1).setValue(rdWOValue);
        wipSheet.getRange(wipLastRow + 1, 2).setValue(rdCustomerValue);
        wipSheet.getRange(wipLastRow + 1, 3).setValue(rdQTYValue);
        wipSheet.getRange(wipLastRow + 1, 4).setValue(rdJobNotesValue);

        break;
      }

    }

  }
}
```

It was finding matches and updating them with just the if statement inside the for loop and the block to create a new row worked on its own. When I tried integrating them by adding the else statement, it just started adding a new row even if there was a match.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].  If we can't reproduce the problem then we cannot trouble shoot it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Suggestion

Your `for` loop is comparing all entries in columns `A`, `B`, and `D` on the sheet `WIP` with the values of the row being edited on `Renderings`. As a result, it's expected for the loop to find entries that do not match, satisfying the condition of the `else` statement.

I suggest having the script add a new row only after the `for` loop reaches the end of the array and if it did not find any matches in `WIP`.

Try replacing the existing `for` loop with this:

```
for (var w = 0; w < wipWOValues.length; w++) {
  //pastes values from Rendering sheet to WIP sheet if match is found
  if (wipWOValues[w][0] === rdWOValue && wipCustomerValues[w][0] === rdCustomerValue && wipJobNotesValues[w][0] === rdJobNotesValue) {
    wipQTYValues[w][0] = rdQTYValue;
    wipQTY.setValues(wipQTYValues);
    break;
  } else if (w == wipWOValues.length - 1) {
    //adds new row if no match is found after the for loop reaches the end of the array and pastes values from Rendering sheet to WIP sheet
    var wipLastRow = wipSheet.getLastRow();

    wipSheet.getRange(wipLastRow + 1, 1).setValue(rdWOValue);
    wipSheet.getRange(wipLastRow + 1, 2).setValue(rdCustomerValue);
    wipSheet.getRange(wipLastRow + 1, 3).setValue(rdQTYValue);
    wipSheet.getRange(wipLastRow + 1, 4).setValue(rdJobNotesValue);
  }
}
```

Comment: The full program continues after the for loop. So I don't want to return. Could I replace it with something else to skip the next block if it's true? Or do I need to change my if statement? The 3 things I'm trying to match should be in the same row. Is there a better way to do that?

Comment: Thank you for the response. I've edited my answer and adjusted the `for` loop to fit your requirements. With how I configured it, it will check the entirety of the `wipWOValues` array and will only add a new row if it reaches the end of the array with no matches found. Let me know if that works for you.